# Convert Json object to array in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, yaml

```
 Photos:
      - id: Photo1
        Type: Color
        Shade: Grey
      - id: Photo2
        Type: Color
        Shade: Red
```

Here am converting the above yaml file to JSON Object and trying to find a photo based on id:

```
const raw = fs.readFileSync("Photos.yaml", 'utf8');
const PhotoData= YAML.load(raw);

export const getSpecificPhoto = (req,res)=>{
    const { id } = req.params;
    let photoArray = []; //photoArray
    let getPhoto = JSON.stringify(PhotoData);  //Converting to JSON string

    photoArray.push(getPhoto); //Pushing to arrayv so that search can be done
    console.log(photoArray);
    const foundPhoto = photoArray.find((photo) => photo.id == id);

    console.log(foundPhoto );
}
```

The following results are obtained on :

```
console.log(photoArray) => {"Photos":[{"id":"Photo1","Type":"Color","Shade":"Grey"},{"id":"Photo2","Type":"Color","Shade":"Red"}]}

console.log(foundPhoto) => undefined
```

Problem : I am suspecting that getting of "Photos":  in result of console.log(photoArray) is causing my search of photo based on id to fail. How to remove this ? I believe if this gets removed searching and returning of photo will work

Comment: you are pushing `getLayout` shouldnt that be `getPhoto ` ? Also `stringify` converts objects to json strings, not object.. You need to `JSON.parse()` that string.

Comment: Yes it was a mistake while writing it here on stack overflow.Corrected that

Comment: There seems to be a disconnect here. `photoArray` prints an object, but nowhere in code reassigns `photoArray` from an array to an object.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/), and `JSON.stringify()`, as the name already suggests, returns a string.

Comment: Corrected it @Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is insode `Photos` object, and then you push in an empty array.
So when you find from the array, you need to get it from the correct position.

Correct code:

```js
(function test(id) {
let PhotoData = "{\"Photos\":[{\"id\":\"Photo1\", \"Type\": \"Color\", \"Shade\": \"Grey\"}, {\"id\": \"Photo2\", \"Type\": \"Color\", \"Shade\": \"Red\"}]}"
let photoArray = []; //photoArray
let getPhoto = JSON.parse(PhotoData);  //Converting to JSON object
console.log(getPhoto);
photoArray.push(getPhoto); //Pushing to arrayv so that search can be done
console.log(photoArray);
const foundPhoto = photoArray[0].Photos.find((photo) => photo.id == id);

console.log(foundPhoto );
})("Photo1");
```

Result:

```
{id: "Photo1", Type: "Color", Shade: "Grey"}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's strange that you convert this object with photos back to a string with `JSON.stringify()` and then add that string to an array. See my suggestion below.

```js
const existingArrayOfPhotos = [];

yamlString = `Photos:
      - id: Photo1
        Type: Color
        Shade: Grey
      - id: Photo2
        Type: Color
        Shade: Red`
        
const photoData = YAML.parse(yamlString);
existingArrayOfPhotos.push(...photoData.Photos)
const foundPhoto = existingArrayOfPhotos.find((photo) => photo.id == "Photo1");

console.log(foundPhoto);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/yamljs/0.3.0/yaml.min.js"></script>
```